# Prove the equality of two outer measures

Tags: measure-theory

We define 
$$
n^*(A)=\lim_{\varepsilon\downarrow0} n_{\varepsilon}^{*}(A)
$$
and
$$
n_{\varepsilon}^{*}(A) = \inf Z_{A}^{\varepsilon}
$$
with 
$$
Z_{A}^{\varepsilon} = \left\{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\ell(I_{n})}:I_{n} \text{ are intervals with length $\geq\varepsilon$},A\subseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_{n}\right\}.
$$

We now need to prove that, given $A$ is compact, $n^{*}(A)=m^*(A)$.

Since proving $m^*(A)\leq n^{*}(A)$ is easy, by proving the inequality $n^{*}(A)\leq m^*(A)$, we have equality of $n^{*}(A)$ and $m^{*}(A)$. I'm having trouble proving the latter.

Comment: Is $m^*$ Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that.

Comment: $A$ compact means that in the definition of $m^*$ you can take finite collections of intervals (provided we use open intervals), so their length is bounded from below by some $\epsilon>0$.